# RealtimePi (preemt rt)

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, realtime

Как видите, программа создает частоту на GPIO 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
 
int main()
{
    const sched_param sp={20};
    pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(),SCHED_FIFO,&sp);   
    mlockall(MCL_FUTURE|MCL_CURRENT);
 
    wiringPiSetup();
    pinMode(0,OUTPUT);
 
    while(true)
    {
        digitalWrite(0,true);
        digitalWrite(0,false);  
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Я скачал rt linux для raspberry pi в надежде, что он мне поможет генерировать высокую и стабильную частоту.
http://unofficialpi.org/Distros/RealtimePi/

Очень плохо понимаю как орудывать этой rt и как с помощью нее добиться поставленной цели.
Может я что то не так делаю подскажите пожалуйста.

Частота 25 килогерц, иногда подпрыгивает до 300.
Как ее сохранить на 300 стабильно или больше по средствам rt?

И киньте пожалуйста инструкцию как этой rt управлять с описанием команд и куда их писать (желательно на русском).
А то везде только или как ее установить или теория.

Comment: У raspberry pi есть 4 пина с ШИМ (PWM), можно использовать их, все будет хорошо https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/

Comment: я поменял 0 на 26, то есть на тот который в ссылке, все тоже самое, мне нужно не шим а просто частота - импульсы, стандартные функции для шим из под python я пробовал - они очень плохой сигнал генерируют и частота маленькая

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как всегда, все уже написано до нас.
Смотрите ссылку: [тут](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4906/control-hardware-pwm-frequency)

Мой опыт **аппаратной реализации ШИМ** такой:

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main (void)
{
  printf ("Raspberry Pi wiringPi test program\n") ;

  if (wiringPiSetupGpio() == -1)
    exit (1) ;

  pinMode(18,PWM_OUTPUT);
  pwmSetClock(20);
  pwmSetRange (10) ;
  pwmWrite (18, 5);

for (;;) delay (1000) ;
}
```

**Аппаратная реализация** ШИМ доступна на 4-х пинах GPIO12, GPIO13, GPIO18, GPIO19.

Частота выставлена в 480кГц. **Результат**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Еще бы не помешали комментарии к этому коду, что именно происходит при вызове каждой функции и как в целом эта штука (вместе с ОС)  работает

Comment: @avp Ну я же не могу сделать полный экскурс в raspbian и в библиотеку wiringpi. Есть описание библиотеки (http://wiringpi.com/). Ищите описание каждой функции там. Если коротко, то инициализируется библиотека, после пин 18 переключается в режим аппаратного ШИМ, устанавливается предделитель частоты в 20, после чего устанавливается диапазон ШИМ в 10 (если хотите, то это делитель частоты ШИМ) и далее устанавливается длительность пульса в тактах поделенной частоты ШИМ (у меня стоит 5, чтобы скважность была 2). Читайте доки, они открыты и доступны

Comment: Циклическая подача 0/1 на 18-й пин это аппаратная фича данного GPIO (задается `PWM_OUTPUT`) или цикл обеспечивается обработчиком прерываний от таймера из библиотеки?

Comment: @avp Да, это аппаратная реализация ШИМа, сама библиотека умеет еще и программную реализацию ШИМа, через внутренний таймер библиотеки, но там скорости очень низкие и можно использовать только 1 ШИМ в каждый момент времени, но зато можно выводить на любые пины, а не только на те, которые умеют в аппаратный ШИМ.

Comment: ОК. Собственно, именно этот момент стоит отметить в ответе, чтобы автор вопроса понял разницу между ним и используемым им в коде вопроса подходе

Comment: спасибо, частота хорошая нужно теперь понять как управлять частотой через этот ШИМ

Comment: @LuaКолдун Управлять частотой можно через команды `pwmSetClock();  pwmSetRange()`.  Но управлять в большом диапазоне не получится. Удастся менять частоту только дискретно и с большим шагом.

Comment: блин возникла еще одна проблема если я так делаю то я не могу считать количество импульсов, то есть мне надо например 100 импульсов сгенерировать, а потом остановить, можно ли как-то это реализовать?

for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        digitalWrite(0,true);
        digitalWrite(0,false);  
    }

Comment: @LuaКолдун Во-первых, в Вашем вопросе этого не было (того, что Вам нужно генерить N импульсов c определенным периодом и определенной длительностью), в вопросе была только генерация частоты. Во-вторых, способ предлагаемый Вами в комментарии выше не годится для любой операционной системы (linux, windows, rtos) поскольку в них происходит переключение между потоками и следовательно существует время когда ваша программа работать не будет. Только аппаратные средства.

Comment: @LuaКолдун Могу порекомендовать использовать SPI на RPI, но нет уверенности, что не будет задержки между словами. Но частоту и количество импульсов Вы соблюдете  (Например, можно посылать 0x55 - это как раз 4 импульса с частотой в 2 раза меньше, чем частота SPI, смотрите импульсы на выходе SPI_MOSI, а если посылаете 0xf0 - то это один импульс с частотой в 8 раз меньше, чем частота SPI. Готовите массив из N таких импульсов и шлете через SPI)